# Google wallet automatic fund deduction life cycle

Tags: android, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, android-pay

I am working on a Cab application like Uber, integrating google wallet as payment gateway but do't know how to deduct amount from user's card attached in google wallet at the time when ride is complete.

Answer (score 0):

Google Wallet isn't for making payments, it's for moving [money between people](https://www.google.ca/wallet/faq/).  If you're talking about using Stripe with Android Pay, you can find out more about implementing that in your Android app [here](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android).  You can find out about Stripe Connect - Stripe's 'platform building' product - [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect).